# Помогите разобраться с ошибкой

Tags: c#, .net, регулярные-выражения

Есть объект, наследованный от `IEnumerable`. В методе `MoveNext` этого класса возникает `StackOverflowException` на строчке с `Regex`. Само регулярное выражение ищет совпадения текста в файлах. Что примечательно, на Windows 10 x64 c .Net 4.6 все работает, ошибка возникает на Windows 7 x64 c .Net 4.0.

У меня есть 2 предположения почему так происходит:

1. Первое: возможно, из-за отличий реализации метода `Regex` в .Net 4.0 и .Net 4.6 `Regex` занимает больше памяти в стеке и поэтому падает с exception.
2. Второе: может быть, размер стека в Win10 отличается от такового в Win7.

Как проверить текущий размер стека? Как проверить доступный размер стека? И какие еще могут быть причины данной ошибки?

Количество файлов в `IEnumerable`, по которым идет поиск — 2760 (`_objEnumerator.Count`), каждый файл подгружается заранее и хранится в качестве строки в этом самом `IEnumerable`. Ниже приведен примерный код:

```
private class MyEnumerator : IEnumerable
{
    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        if (_objEnumerator == null)
        {
            _objEnumerator = _objects.GetEnumerator();
        }

        Match m;

        if (_current == null)
        {
            if (!_objEnumerator.MoveNext())
                return false;

            m = _regex.Match((_objEnumerator.Current).Text); // (_objEnumerator.Current).Text хранит  текст файла, ошибка падает в этой строчке
        }           

        if (m.Success)
        {
           // код выдающий результат
           return true;
        }
        else
        {
           _current = null;
           return MoveNext();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Включите в ответ информацию по ошибке: тип, трассировку стека.

Comment: @defaultlocale возникает StackOverflow Exception в этом случае трассировка стека средствами студии недоступна, попробую получить его через WinDbg

Comment: Попробуйте заменить хвостовую рекурсию на цикл.

Comment: P.S. А чем Вас LINQ не устраивает? `_objects.Select(o => _regex.Match(o.Text)).Where(m => m.Success).Select(m => /* код выдающий результат */)`

Comment: @PetSerAl код не мой, на момент когда он писался Linq возможно еще не было, попробую изменить, отпишусь по результатам

Comment: @PetSerAl да, итеративный метод помог, спасибо! Но почему это работает в Win10 так и не понятно, по идее там стек так же должен был забиваться. Может действительно в 10ке размер стека больше. Попробую провести тест. Оформите как ответ?

Comment: Если хотите писать красивые рекурсивные функции - то вам нужно учить `F#` :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Проблема, думаю, именно из-за рекурсии (глубина 2700, это много). В .NET начиная, кажется, с 4.5, перешли на новый JIT-компилятор, который умеет определять хвостовую рекурсию, и производить вызов `tailcall` вместо нормального рекурсивного вызова. В результате стек не забивается.

---

Поскольку наличие оптимизации хвостовой рекурсии не гарантировано языком (и, кажется, не работает на 32-битных таргетах до сих пор), рекурсивная реализация — это баг в коде. Перепишите вашу функцию итеративно.

---

Уточнение: я попробовал код, аналогичный вашему, и он не генерирует в VS 2015/.NET 4.5/x64/Release хвостовой вызов в IL-коде. Значит, ваша проблема может быть не в этом. Я попробую расследовать причину дальше.

---

Дальнейшее расследование: В текущей версии .NET (4.5) хвостовая рекурсия не требует IL-префикса `tail`. Пример: вот такой код

```
class Program
{
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t = new Program();
        t.f(1);
        Console.ReadKey();        // здесь можно приаттачить отладчик
        t.f(100000000);
    }

    int f(int iterNo)
    {
        new DateTime(2017, 2, 3); // увеличим размер кода функции, чтобы сделать
                                  // хвостовую оптимизацию привлекательной для JIT
        if (iterNo == 0)
            return 0;
        else
            return f(iterNo - 1);
    }
}
```

генерирует следующий IL, **без** префикса `.tail`:

```
  .method private hidebysig instance int32 
          f(int32 iterNo) cil managed
  {
    // Code size       28 (0x1c)
    .maxstack  8
//000021: 
//000022:      int f(int iterNo)
//000023:      {
//000024:          new DateTime(2017, 2, 3); // увеличим размер кода функции, чтобы сделать
    IL_0000:  ldc.i4     0x7e1
    IL_0005:  ldc.i4.2
    IL_0006:  ldc.i4.3
    IL_0007:  newobj     instance void [mscorlib]System.DateTime::.ctor(int32,
                                                                        int32,
                                                                        int32)
    IL_000c:  pop
//000025:                                    // хвостовую оптимизацию привлекательной для JIT
//000026:          if (iterNo == 0)
    IL_000d:  ldarg.1
    IL_000e:  brtrue.s   IL_0012

//000027:              return 0;
    IL_0010:  ldc.i4.0
    IL_0011:  ret

//000028:          else
//000029:              return f(iterNo - 1);
    IL_0012:  ldarg.0
    IL_0013:  ldarg.1
    IL_0014:  ldc.i4.1
    IL_0015:  sub
    IL_0016:  call       instance int32 Tailcall.Program::f(int32)
    IL_001b:  ret
  } // end of method Program::f
```

Тем не менее, нативный код для `f` выглядит так:

```
   24:             new DateTime(2017, 2, 3); // увеличим размер кода функции, чтобы сделать
push        rdi  
push        rsi  
sub         rsp,28h  
mov         rdi,rcx  
mov         esi,edx  
mov         ecx,7E1h  
mov         edx,2  
mov         r8d,3  
call        000007FEF1361730  
   25:                                       // хвостовую оптимизацию привлекательной для JIT
   26:             if (iterNo == 0)
test        esi,esi  
jne         000007FE932A053D  
   27:                 return 0;
xor         eax,eax  
add         rsp,28h  
pop         rsi  
pop         rdi  
ret  
lea         edx,[rsi-1]                  // вычли 1
mov         rcx,rdi
mov         rax,7FE932A0080h  
add         rsp,28h                      // очистили фрейм
pop         rsi  
pop         rdi  
jmp         rax                          // переход вместо возврата
```

Это означает, что хвостовая рекурсия *может быть применена на JIT-уровне*, без участия IL-компилятора. Поэтому то, что в .NET 4.5 новый JIT-компилятор, вполне могло помочь.

В любом случае, правильное решение проблемы — переписывание кода итеративным образом.

Comment: csc для Win10 показало Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.6.1586.0
for C# 5 А для Win7 Visual C# Compiler version 4.0.30319

Comment: конфигурация проекта AnyCpu/Debug VS2010

Comment: @user2455111: Debug? Ох. Это важно. Расследую дальше.

Comment: @user2455111: А не могли бы вы скинуть полный код вашего класса? У меня не получилось состряпать код, который бы воспроизводил проблему.

Comment: там все настолько завязано, что придется скидывать всю библиотеку, а возможно и проект (чего я сделать не могу), я попробую воспроизвести ее в отдельном проекте, если получится и скинуть вам этот проект. Ну и постараюсь привести пример класса, только вот куда его кинуть

Comment: @user2455111: Ну, на любой файлообменник по идее? А можно воспроизвести проблему на более маленьком классе? Убрать куда-то `_objects` и всё такое, и заменить на просто список из 2800 элементов?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52638/discussion-between-user2455111-and-vladd).